# How to ignore %% from being evaluated?

Tags: batch-file, variables, dos

One of my variables has the value `%val%` - this is exactly the name!

So: `set variable=%val%`

What happens now is that when running the script the variable will be set to nothing as the `%val%` is being evaluated! But this is not what I want... How can I tell DOS to ignore the %-sign here?

Answer (score 1):

Use double `%` characters to escape a single one:

```
set variable=%%val%%
```

Look [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) for different kinds of escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET variable=%%var%%

ECHO %variable%

PAUSE
```

Works on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
set variable="%val%"
```

Comment: This does not work at my location ... :( But the solutions above are perfectly fine!
Thanks a lot for your help here!

Comment: @murxx - If the solutions work, make sure to mark them as an answer, and upvote the ones you find useful.